# Where exactly are the 2 unwanted args that I have supposedly passed?

Tags: python, function, scale, typeerror, args

I am not familiar with Python scripting. I am simply trying to create a small GUI that will allow me to alter a parameter in an ArcGIS Model using the Tkinter Scale and then run the model by clicking a TKinter Button. (The code below is not finished and is being used for testing purposes, hence the button does not actually call a different script yet).

I get this TypeError in the Traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: GetScale() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

I have tried deleting many different things from my code to determine what these arguments might be but to no avail. It is incredibly frustrating as I am sure it is the most simple problem.

My code is as follows:

```
import Tkinter

from Tkinter import *

class createBuffer(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        #Define variable for text field
        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)

        #Set default text field text
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter desired radius here.")

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Create Buffer",
                            command = self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1, row=0)



        scale = Tkinter.Scale(self, variable = StringVar, orient = HORIZONTAL, from_ =              0, to = 100, resolution = 10, width = 30, length = 300, command = self.GetScale)
        scale.grid(row = 4)
        scale.set(50)



        #Create a Tkinter variable and bind it to a widget
        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self, textvariable = self.labelVariable,
                          anchor = "w", fg = "black", bg = "white")
        label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="EW")
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Radius:")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)

        #Fix the size of the window as its own size (doesn't automatically resize with long text string input)
        #self.update()
        #self.geometry(self.geometry())



        #set focus to text field 
        self.entry.focus_set()        
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)


    def OnButtonClick(self):
        self.labelVariable.set("Radius:    " +self.entryVariable.get())

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set("Radius:    " + self.entryVariable.get())
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def GetScale():
        sliderValue = scale.get()
        print (sliderValue)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = createBuffer(None)
    app.title('Buffer Tool')
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
return self.func(*args)
```

There are two arguments, one implicit and one explicit. The first one is implicit, and it's `self`. Whenever you call a function that's attached to an object, aka `obj.func()`, the `obj` object itself is the implicit first argument. The second argument is the `*args` array which is being passed in explicitly, and even if it contains zero arguments, it still counts as an argument in itself (though it just contains an empty tuple `()`).

Now look at the following line in your code:

`scale = Tkinter.Scale(self, variable = StringVar, orient = HORIZONTAL, from_ =              0, to = 100, resolution = 10, width = 30, length = 300, command = self.GetScale)`

Here, you're passing in `GetScale()` as a function argument, and it's being called in the above way in the `Tkinter` module somewhere. The module is basically calling `self.GetScale(*args)`. As ambi suggested, you'll need to change the definition of `GetScale()`, probably to this:

```
def GetScale(self, *args):
    sliderValue = scale.get()
    print (sliderValue)
```

On a less related note, if you want each of your objects to have a `scale` variable, it might be smarter to refer to it as `self.scale`. If it's a global `scale`, then ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

Change definition of `GetScale` function to:

```
def GetScale(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    sliderValue = scale.get()
    print (sliderValue)
```

This way your function will accept any positional or keyword arguments so you can check what these are.

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
def GetScale():
    sliderValue = scale.get()
    print (sliderValue)
```

should instead be:

```
def GetScale(self):
    sliderValue = scale.get()
    print (sliderValue)
```

Since it is a class method you must list 'self' as an argument because it will be automatically passes to the function when it is called. As far as the second argument goes I'm not entirely sure about it. When you bind a method to a TK command such as

```
command = GetScale
```

you must omit the parenthesis to avoid the call happening prematurely. This means that you cannot pass additional arguments as far as I know. I would start with making the correct changes to your GetScale function and see if it positively changes your output/errors.

Comment: Where do you need the self argument?